# mysql - how to save results from DESCRIBE table into table

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, sql-insert, mariadb-10.1

I'm trying to implement the following code but doesn't seem to work in mysql:

```
insert into table2
DESCRIBE table1;
```

or

```
insert into table2
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table1;
```

any help is appreciated.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use such a way through use of `information_schema.columns` :

```
CREATE TABLE table2(colname varchar(100), coltype varchar(100));

CREATE TABLE table1(col1 varchar(100), col2 int);

INSERT INTO table2
SELECT column_name, data_type 
  FROM information_schema.columns 
 WHERE table_name = 'table1'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8775fbd2a64ef2b4f6c02bcaa9bcc0f6)</kbd>

*The DDL and DML statements are mixed, which is violation, within your cases.*

Comment: seems that the version of my mariadb does not support this: 10.1.17-MariaDB

Comment: I apologize this works perfectly, tested the code below and it worked SELECT column_name, data_type 
  FROM information_schema.columns 
 WHERE table_name = 'questions';